# How to implement the getElementByClassName()

Tags: javascript

I've got an application which contains a list and looks like this:

[image: list]

When I click on each tick, the name of the Book is added to a textbox below and I want the tick to be replaced with a cross where the user can remove it.

As it stands, when I click any of the ticks, only the first list items box changes to a cross like this:

[image: cross]

However, I want whatever tick is alongside the book to change to a cross not the first one at the top of the list.

I know this issue has something to do with the items needing to be a class element rather than ID as using an ID tag will always select the first item with that ID. However, i'm unsure how to implement it into my code as i've tried wrapping the tick and cross boxes in divs with a class name and still the same thing happens.

The JS code looks like this:

```js
function saveToList(event) {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) { 
    
function saveToFB(bookName) {
  
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var bookList = firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid + '/');
var uid = user.uid;

// This will save data to Firebase
bookList.push({
    book: bookName
    });
};

// This is JS which creates the list from firebase data. Split into 3 lists holding 10 books each
function refreshUI(list) {
var lis = '';
var lis2 = '';
var lis3 = '';

for (var i = 0; i < 10 && i < list.length; i++) {

// Creates the list item by adding the firebase object + genLinks which contains the select, remove and delete icons. 
lis += '<li data-key="' + list[i].key + '">' + list[i].book + genLinks(list[i].key, list[i].book) +'</li>';
      };
      
for (var i = 10; i < 20 && i < list.length; i++) {
      
lis2 += '<li data-key="' + list[i].key + '">' + list[i].book + genLinks(list[i].key, list[i].book) +'</li>';
      };
      
for (var i = 20; i < 30 && i < list.length; i++) {
      
 lis3 += '<li data-key="' + list[i].key + '">' + list[i].book + genLinks(list[i].key, list[i].book) +'</li>';
      };
      
      // Populates the HTML lists with the JS list items
        document.getElementById('bookList').innerHTML = lis;
        document.getElementById('bookList2').innerHTML = lis2;
        document.getElementById('bookList3').innerHTML = lis3;
    };



// This is the area of the JS concerned with generating the icons found alongside each book name and where I need help 



// The google icons wrapped in divs with class names
function genLinks(key, bkName) {
var links = '';
links += '<a href="javascript:del(\'' + key + '\',\'' + bkName + '\')"><div class="deleteBook"><i id="deleteBook" class="material-icons">delete</i></div></a> ';
links += '<a href="javascript:remove(\'' + key + '\',\'' + bkName + '\')"><div class="removeBook"><i id="removeBook" class="material-icons" onclick="showAdd()" style="display: none">clear</i></div></a> ';
links += '<a href="javascript:select(\'' + key + '\',\'' + bkName + '\')"><div class="selectBook"><i id="selectBook" class="material-icons" onclick="showRemove()">check</i></div></a>';
return links;
};


// onClick event from the selectBook icon which hides the tick and replaces with a cross
function showRemove() {
  document.getElementById('removeBook').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('selectBook').style.display = 'none';
}

// onClick event from the removeBook icon which hides the cross and replaces with a tick
function showAdd() {
  document.getElementById('selectBook').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('removeBook').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div id="bookListContainer">
    <ol id="bookList"> </ol>
    
    <ol id="bookList2"> </ol>
    
    <ol id="bookList3"> </ol>
</div>
```

I was told by somebody to use getElementsByClassName() but they gave no explanation on how to do so. If anybody has any advice or could offer some help I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,

G

Comment: So to clarify: You're looking for a tutorial on how to use `getElementsByClassName`? And you'd like us to rewrite your code to use it?

Comment: Have you [read any documentation about `getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)?

Comment: CSS with checkboxes would make this so much easier.

Comment: Open up dev tools and play around in the console:
    document.getElementsByClassName("class_name");

Comment: Why don't you use simple `$('.class-name');` and `$.each()`?

Comment: @RohanKumar perhaps because the OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: apologies @RohanKumar - I wonder why Keith decided to to remove that tag, surely the OP included the tag for a reason :p

Comment: Don't worry it happens when we don't see behind the scenes. Yes, I agree with your point. @Keith must have to justify the reason.

Comment: You know, there is a thing called a search engine, perhaps you should try it, it's the latest fad

Comment: @JaromandaX there's no jQuery in the sample code, the question doesn't refer to jQuery, and a good answer to this question probably wouldn't require downloading an additional library the rest of the code doesn't need. This isn't a jQuery question.

Comment: @Keith - yeah, I hate jquery too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to control the icon that is displayed. Also using checkboxes makes it easy to know what is selected. Than it is a simple query and loop to get the checked items.

```js
function buildList() {
   /* Get the checked checkboxes */
   var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[name="books"]:checked');
   /* Build up list of the values by looping over the elements */
   var out = [];    
   for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
       out.push(checkboxes[i].value);       
   }
   /* Join list together and display it */
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = out.join(", ")
}
document.getElementById("booklist").addEventListener("change", buildList);
buildList();
```

```css
[name="books"] {  /* Hide checkbox */
  display: none
}

[name="books"]+i+i { /* Hide the x when not checked */
  display: none
}

[name="books"]:checked+i {  /* Hide the check when checked */
  display: none
}

[name="books"]:checked+i+i { /* show the x when checked */
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul id="booklist">
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 1</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book1" name="books" />
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 2</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book2" name="books" checked/>
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 3</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book3" name="books" />
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 4</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book4" name="books" />
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="output"></div>
```

And we can alter it slightly to handle multiple lists. This time we can use a data attribute to say where to output the item. And we use a loop to add the event listeners to the parents.

```js
(function() {
  function buildList(listId) {
    /* Get the checked checkboxes */
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#' + listId + ' [name="books"]:checked');
    /* Build up list of the values by looping over the elements */
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      out.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
    var outputId = document.getElementById(listId).dataset.output;
    /* Join list together and display it */
    document.getElementById(outputId).innerHTML = out.join(", ")
  }


  var lists = document.querySelectorAll(".book-list");
  for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    (function(list) {
      list.addEventListener("change", function() {
        buildList(list.id)
      });
      buildList(list.id);
    }(lists[i]))
  }
}());
```

```css
[name="books"] {
  /* Hide checkbox */
  display: none
}

[name="books"]+i+i {
  /* Hide the x when not checked */
  display: none
}

[name="books"]:checked+i {
  /* Hide the check when checked */
  display: none
}

[name="books"]:checked+i+i {
  /* show the x when checked */
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul id="booklist1" class="book-list" data-output="output1">
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 1</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book1" name="books" />
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 2</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book2" name="books" checked/>
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 3</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book3" name="books" />
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 4</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book4" name="books" />
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="output1"></div>

<ul id="booklist2" class="book-list" data-output="output2">
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 5</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book5" name="books" />
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 6</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book6" name="books"/>
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 7</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book7" name="books" />
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <span>Book 8</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="book8" name="books" />
      <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="output2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a really detailed and helpful example! Just need to try and alter it to work with my list types now!:)

Answer (score 0):

The functions showremove and showadd can only change one id, aka one box. If it's supposed to work with more than one box you should change selectbook and removebook to a class and add an index to access an individual one.